# Sending string data to server script using volley in android fragment

Tags: java, android

Am trying to send data received from my android app to a server side php script. Am using the Volley. However, when I declare the the RequestQueue I get an error 
"newRequestQueue (android.content.Context, com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack) cannot be applied to ()"

I tried using::

> Blockquote

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

> Blockquote

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

> Blockquote

Error is still the same on both cases. Please what am doing wrong? 
PS- volley is in PostDataToEmail method of a fragment.

Here is the code below:

```
public void PostDataToEmail(){
    final String service  = service_type.toString();
    final String error_message = incident.getText().toString();
    final String requester = user_name.getText().toString();
    final String number = mobile_no.getText().toString();
    final String site = location.getText().toString();
    final String support_time = timeDate.getText().toString();
    final String support_date = date_field.getText().toString();
    final String mode_of_contact = contact_mode.toString();

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue();
    String url = "http://mywebsite/fromApp.php";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest (Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "error => " +error.toString());
                }
            }
                )   {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("grant_type", "password");
            params.put(" ", "{{%escape/");
            params.put("Service: ", service);
            params.put("Error Message: ", error_message);
            params.put("Requester: ", requester);
            params.put("Mobile No: ", number);
            params.put("Location: ", site);
            params.put("Time: ", support_time);
            params.put("Date: ", support_date);
            params.put("Contact mode: ", mode_of_contact);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in your declaration. `RequestQueue some=newRequestQueue(this)`